# ssh - Simple sharing files solution 

Tags: ssh, network-shares, file-transfer, openssh

The first time I use ssh connect ( putty ) when I try to share my contents from my windows and Linux ( VirtualBox ) . 
I find it's quite fast to share contents through ssh . And I've found that windows doesn't have ssh included ( we must use openssh for windows ) .
Anyone how a good and clean way to share files using ssh client. It's really the simplest way, it doesn't depend on OS :)
Is it possible ? I'm looking for your answer :P

Comment: If you are looking to share files between a guest and host in VirtualBox, consider using the Shared Folders functionality from within VirtualBox guest additions.

Comment: @fostandy : I don't looking for a way to share between virtual PC . I'm looking for a sharing methods for all OS ( virtual ) using ssh :)

Answer (score 2):

scp - on windows there's winscp as a file transfer client (its also a good ftp client). There's also a ssh server for windows - in copessh or freessh.

Comment: Can you post a detail how we setup this :)
I really don't have two pcs right now . So I can't test :(

Comment: naw, you can get an SSH server set up on windows, - both of the ones i mentioned are rather straightforward installs. SCP.. select an IP address (localhost if you want to play around with it ) and a means of transfer and it should work

Answer (score 0):

use [fuse+sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) it works great on mac and linux.  Haven't tried it on windows but you only need it on the client to make it work.